# Bitrix Передаём пользовательские свойства в корзину

Tags: php, битрикс

У меня есть проект на bitrix там есть ajax корзина и добавляю я туда товар таким образом:

```
if (Add2BasketByProductID($offerID, 1, [], [['CODE' => 'INCREASE', 'VALUE' => $increase],
        ['CODE' => 'INCREASE_ALL', 'VALUE' => $increase_all]]) === false) { ?>
    <div class="add-basket">
        <div class="add-basket__head">Товар не найден</div>
    </div>
<? return; }
```

Вообщем-то всё работает товар добавляется, но параметры которые я передаю в данном случае `INCREASE и INCREASE_ALL` не отображеются в корзине от слова совсем. Как заставить их там показываться ?? К слову свойство `INCREASE_ALL` у товара и правда есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, я мало того, что немного неправильно написал вызов функции, хотя вроде и такой рабочий, так еще и оказывается, что когда передаёшь данные NAME нажо указывать обязательно, вот такой код рабочий:

```
Add2BasketByProductID($offerID, 1, [['NAME' => 'Наценка', 'CODE' => 'INCREASE', 'VALUE' => $increase], ['NAME' => 'Общая наценка', 'CODE' => 'INCREASE_ALL', 'VALUE' => $increase_all]])
```